# Background image spanning multiple divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, background

I'm trying to use a single background image over multiple divs arranged in a grid. See the link and picture below. Although my method of using `background-attachment: fixed;` on all the `.box-icon` divs gives the desired effect, I also have to use `background-size: cover;` to ensure that it will always cover all the `.box-icon`s which seems to be `cover`ing the entire document, not just the area taken up by the boxes, which makes it look ugly (see screenshots). Adjusting the width of the page, or zooming, demonstrates what I'm talking about.

Is there a better way to `cover` all the `.box-icon`s with a single background such that it is *only* covering that small area responsively and won't blow up the image? CSS/jQuery/javascript solutions are all accepted!

Here is a [link to my website](http://people.reed.edu/~jhawkins/home.html); the relevant files are `./css/style.css` and `./home.html`.

I have a [JSFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/hjagw31f/). Try resizing the viewer window to see. Also notice how the background-image glitches out when scrolling :(

I have an [album of example screenshots here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkp3u.jpg). The background changes each time and the other images show the ugly blown-up-ness better.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hjagw31f/

Comment: could you not just fake this with a single background `div` and spacer 'cover's or larger border's so that you're only applying the background once and will scale to its container, rather than trying to align things with all the separate `div`s

Comment: I thought about that but then it would complicate how the visual effects are achieved. I don't know how the boxes would animate individually if the background image were really from another `div` element.

Answer (score 1):

---

Explicitly specifying the background size would work.

http://jsfiddle.net/derrickmv/snw9j7wf/

```
.box-icon {
        background-size: 210px 420px;
        background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/LGKO1Zm.jpg');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position: inherit;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        border: 2px solid red;
        z-index: 5;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Basically, sizing the background image along the sum of each box's size.
(hopefully I made sense)

Comment: Yeah that makes sense except then it's not responsive as the screen size changes since the boxes are relatively sized.